# What is the best tool to recover data from Centos Linux volumes

Tags: centos, dracut

I have this error when starting Centos 7,

```
[ 198.942749] dracut-initqueuel3371: Warning: /dev/centos/root does not exist
[ 198.9438971 dracut-initqueue[337]: Warning: /dev/centos/swap does not exist
[ 198.9433781 dracut-initqueue[337]: Warning: /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-00a7896a:5363ef2f:ccd81c8f:8e11e69e does not exist
[ 198.9436701 dracut-initqueue[337]: Warning: /dev/mapper/centos-root does not exist

Starting Dracut Emergency Shell...

Warning: /dev/centos/root does not exist
Varning: /dev/centos/swp does not exist
Warning: /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-md-uuid-00a7896a:5363ef2f:ccd81c8f:8e11e69e does not exist
Warning: /dev/mapper/centos-root does not exist
```

Since I can not restore the boot system, I'm looking for tools to help recover my data from the partitions.

Comment: Boot with https://gparted.org/livecd.php, check partition table. If necessary, chroot and fix stuff. If there are no partitions, try to recover them with gparted. If that fails... well, DR services are your best bet.